# Convert old version logic to Quartz-2.2.1

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Can anyone please help me to change the below logic to the newer version Quartz-2.2.1.

```
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail ( getName(), getClName(), EventJob.class())
```

and

```
Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger ("schedule name", "scheduled",
jobDetail.getName(), jobDetail.getGroup(),
" 0 0/5 * * * ? ",
getTimeZone());
```

Can you please help me on this?
Regards
Rekha

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

// Job Detail
JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(EventJob.class)
    .withIdentity(getName(), getClName())
    .build();

// Trigger
CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("schedule name","scheduled").forJob(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), jobDetail.getKey().getGroup()).withSchedule(cronSchedule(" 0 0/5 * * * ? ").inTimeZone(getTimeZone())).build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

You would also need to make sure that you are importing static methods of builder classes as mentioned in [TriggerBuilder 2.2.1](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html)

```
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
```

Comment: Hi Ritesh Thanks for your reply. Then where should I give jobDetail.getName() and jobDetail.getGroup(). In your code there is no logic for this. Where should I include this?

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. My application flow works fine. Really thanks